# Arbitrary looping in Django templating language

Tags: html, django-templates

In the Django template language is it possible to do a for loop (or anything equivalent) for a specified number of times? I'd like to do something like {% for i in 1,2,3 %}.

My rational in wanting this is I have a stretch of HTML code that differs in only a few places and it would be nice to do

```
{% for i in 1,2,3 %}
//large amount of code
{% cycle 'A', 'B', 'C' as current %}
<a href='#'>{{ current }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

rather than

```
//large amount of code
<a href='#'>A</a>
//large amount of code (again)
<a href='#'>B</a>
//large amount of code (yet again)
<a href='#'>C</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same issue, here's how I did it:

```
    {% for c in "123456789" %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ c }}</td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

A little hackish, but it got the job done.